# How to define a Revit app bundle for Design Automation API that supports multiple Activities

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I'd like to define a Revit app bundle whose DLL defines multiple `IExternalDBApplication` classes, each of which would correspond to its own Activity. This way, a work item for a given Activity would invoke the corresponding `IExternalDBApplication`, but all Activities would refer to the same app bundle.

I have done something similar using the AutoCAD engine -> I would define a method annotated with `[CommandMethod("CUSTOM_COMMAND_NAME")]`, and then in the `PackageContents.xml` file, I could link the command to a class via the `<Commands>` tag, and finally in the Activity definition in Autodesk Forge, we could specify the `settings.script` field with a command that invokes that custom command.

I don't see a way to do this using the Revit engine, at least from reading the tutorial here: https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/revit/.

Is there a way to do this? Or do I need to define a separate app bundle per IExternalDBApplication I'd like to create? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it stands today, Design Automation for Revit acknowledges / recognizes only one `<FolderName>.bundle` folder in the `appbundle` zip package. It in turn can only have one path to the `<AddinName>.addin` file relative to the folder containing the `PackageContents.xml`. The addin file in turn can only load one assembly and specify full class name of only one implementation of `IExternalDBApplication`.

Given the above constraints, you will most likely not be able to create an app bundle that has 2 or more implementations of `IExternalDBApplication` and use a "switch" in different activity definitions.

That said, you can still be able to "branch" in your single implementation of `IExternalDBApplication` + single activity, by passing a json argument in the workitem payload. I'd however do something like this only if the 2 different branches are mostly similar. If not, preference would be to have separate app bundles and separate activity definitions, with common code extracted into a common dll shared by both app bundles.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation! Out of curiosity, how did you find this?  Through experimentation, or maybe there was documentation I missed mentioning those constraints?